# Paper js event example incorrectly tests for mouseenter

Tags: javascript, events, paperjs

I'm using [the code](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#onmouseenter) from mouseenter example, but instead of `view.center` place the circle at `(50;50)`

When the cursor is above the circle, the circle should become red. But it works only with upper left part of it.

Tested in Firefox, Windows 8

```js
$(document).ready(() =>
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas")
    paper.setup(canvas)
    console.log("creating circle")
    var path = new paper.Path.Circle({
        center: new paper.Point(50,50),
        radius: 25,
        fillColor: 'black'
    });
    console.log("created circle")
    // When the mouse enters the item, set its fill color to red:
    path.on('mouseenter', function () {
        this.fillColor = 'red';
    });
    // When the mouse leaves the item, set its fill color to black:
    path.on('mouseleave', function () {
        this.fillColor = 'black';
    });
})
```

```css
canvas {
    border-style:double
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"> </script>
<script src = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.10.3/paper-full.js></script>
<canvas id = "mainCanvas" resize></canvas>
<div>!!</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the CSS to correctly resize the canvas? If the pixels in a HiDPI paper.js canvas don't align then the hit-test will be off:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103200/1163708

Answer (score 0):

Removing `resize` from canvas fixes it. Still interested, if paper.js can work with resized canvas